# Unexplained PHP errror after upgrading to PHP 5.6.27

Tags: php, centos, php-5.6

Running Magento 1.9.x

Anyone seen this before? I just installed PHP 5.6.27 to CentOS 7 and while I can successfully execute workbench PHP scripts, Magento is freaking out about things. I increased the error logging temporarily in Apache as much as possible I'm not seeing anything helpful in the log output.

```
Warning: include(DOMDocument.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

#0 /var/www/html/store/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'Warning: includ...')
#1 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(661): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'Warning: includ...')
#2 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1636): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(964): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterLoad(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '110', NULL)
#5 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '110', NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/store/app/code/local/Agency/Shop/Helper/Product/Plan/Storage/Cookie.php(317): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('110')
#7 /var/www/html/store/app/code/local/Agency/Shop/Helper/Product/Plan/Storage/Cookie.php(204): Agency_Shop_Helper_Product_Plan_Storage_Cookie->getPlan()
#8 /var/www/html/store/app/code/local/Agency/Shop/Helper/Product/Plan/Storage/Abstract.php(518): Agency_Shop_Helper_Product_Plan_Storage_Cookie->getPlanProduct()
#9 /var/www/html/store/app/code/local/Agency/Shop/Block/Product/Plan/Sidebar.php(147): Agency_Shop_Helper_Product_Plan_Storage_Abstract->getPlanDetails()
#10 /var/www/html/store/app/code/local/Agency/Shop/Block/Product/Plan/Sidebar.php(580): Agency_Shop_Block_Product_Plan_Sidebar->_getTotals()
#11 /var/www/html/store/app/design/frontend/bci/default/template/page/html/navigation/bci_navigation-my-cart.phtml(8): Agency_Shop_Block_Product_Plan_Sidebar->getTotals()
#12 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/b...')
#13 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/bci/de...')
#14 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/html/store/app/design/frontend/bci/default/template/page/html/navigation/bci_navigation.phtml(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/b...')
#18 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/bci/de...')
#19 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/html/store/app/design/frontend/bci/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(169): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/b...')
#23 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/bci/de...')
#24 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/html/store/app/code/local/Agency/Shop/Model/Header.php(19): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Container/Abstract.php(104): Agency_Shop_Model_Header->_renderBlock()
#28 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/controllers/RequestController.php(38): Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract->applyInApp('\nprocessAction()
#30 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('process')
#31 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /var/www/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /var/www/html/store/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /var/www/html/store/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#35 {main}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that PHP 5.6 support was only introduced in recent versions of 1.9 - which version are you actually using (not `x`) ? You should also make sure you've installed PHP compiled with all the modules that Magento requires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the requirements:

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html

simplexml and DOM are required modules for Magento.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php